# Java applet of Printer/Scanner device not working properly

Tags: security, java, printer

I have a printer with scanner (Lexmark model CX310).

I can create a scan profile from a Java Applet found in the printer's IP (in my case 192.168.0.28) via a Webbrowser.

Since Chrome and Firefox don't support Java anymore, I used IE11.

I'm using the last version o Java (8 - 151) on Windows 10 64 bits, and I already got permisions on the security tab of Java's configuration window for my IP, as shown in the image.
[image]
But the applet is not working properly as you can see in the picture (the words are not being written) and in the console (it seems something to do with security, access being denied). What should I do?

[image]
[image]

Comment: it's not really a full answer. try adding HTTP://192.168.0.28/* as an exception to the Java security list and see if that works then.

Comment: When I add the *, Java says my appliation was blocked because it's not on the Exception list.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake http://192.168.0.28//*  << added a /

Comment: Doesn't work as well. It says again that I should add the website on the Exception List.

Comment: ok, it may be that wildcards don't work. Could you contact the printer manufacturer for a fix to the UI

Comment: I don't think I can, because this printer version doesn't has technical support anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps too late to answer for the original poster, but still might help someone. Add http://192.168.0.28/ (notice the trailing slash) which means run applets under **/** and **all sub -directories**. Reference
https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml